# How to call NetLocalGroupGetMembers using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, winapi

Anyone can give example how to call **NetLocalGroupGetMembers** using **PowerShell**?

From my searches, I found an example (link below), but I don't know how to use it.

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSReflect-Functions/2.0.0/Content/netapi32%5CNetLocalGroupGetMembers.ps1

Example PowerShell code to call NetLocalGroupGetMembers

Comment: Seen [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/get-localgroupmember?view=powershell-5.1)?

Comment: I think Get-LocalGroupMember cannot be used for Domain Local Group. But I really need specifically to use NetLocalGroupGetMembers.